# Mod_rewrite and subdirectory access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I'm trying to deny access to couple of subdirectories (when using specific url) that are in www-root.

My goal is:

Make domain.com/subdir{1-3} to deny access.

Make subdir{1-3}.domain.com to point to %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir{1-3}. Already works.

I want to write rules to httpd.conf without having to use .htaccess files and use only one Directory section if possible.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<Directory "/var/www/subdir1">
  <IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir1 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

But no go.

//E

Got it working, here's what I did:

```
<Directory />
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir1/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir2/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir3/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir4/
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Is there anything I should change to make it more safe?

Everything works except subdir3 which points to ownclouds root dir. It must have something to do with ownclouds own rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ [R]
RewriteRule ^.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ [R]
RewriteRule ^apps/calendar/caldav.php remote.php/caldav/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^apps/contacts/carddav.php remote.php/carddav/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^apps/([^/]*)/(.*\.(css|php))$ index.php?app=$1&getfile=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^remote/(.*) remote.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Tips are welcome.

Comment: Is that in your htaccess file?

Comment: No, its in httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdir1 - [L,F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdir1\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir1/$1 [L]
```

for "subdir1".

Comment: Nope. domain.com/subdir1 works but subdir1.domain.com doesnt :/